# Android - display an image that is offset by x,y

Tags: android

How do you display a portion of a very large image that is offset at a particular x,y

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Bitmap` using your image and then apply [Bitmap.createBitmap()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method using the `Bitmap` as the source. The method creates a new `Bitmap` using the source, which is offset by given `x` and `y` and has the specified `width` and `height`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

With the android.Graphics.Bitmap and BitmapFactory classes

Open your image -> static Bitmap decodeFile(String pathName)

Extract a subset -> static Bitmap createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height)

Then you should add the subset to a textview to display it.